# How to count and join two tables on mySQL from different database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two databases. Those are `core` and `push`.

This is `subs` table from `core` database:

```
+----+---------+----+----+-----+
| id | service | ad | op | act |
+----+---------+----+----+-----+
| 1  | CHO     | 96 | x  |  1  |
| 2  | CHO     | 98 | x  |  1  |
| 3  | DANG    | 96 | x  |  1  |
| 4  | HOORAY  | 96 | x  |  1  |
| 5  | CHO     | 98 | x  |  1  |
| 6  | DANG    | 96 | x  |  1  |
+----+---------+----+----+-----+
```

and this is the `buff` table from `push` database:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | service |  sub  |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  | DANG    | daily |
| 2  | HOORAY  | daily |
| 3  | DANG    | daily |
+----+---------+-------+
```

i want to count `subs` and `buff`. i made this query for subs:

```
select service, ad, op, count(1) as sub where act=1 group by service,ad,op;

RESULT:
+---------+----+----+-----+
| service | ad | op | sub |
+---------+----+----+-----+
|  CHOO   | 96 | x  |  1  |
|  CHOO   | 98 | x  |  2  |
|  HOORAY | 96 | x  |  1  |
|  DANG   | 96 | x  |  2  |
+---------+----+----+-----+
```

and this is the query for `buff`:

```
select service, count(1) as pushed
from buff a where sub = 'daily'
group by service;

RESULT:
+---------+---------+
| service |  pushed |
+---------+---------+
|  HOORAY |    1    |
|  DANG   |    2    |
+---------+---------+
```

So, my question is how to join those tables from two different databases?
here is the result that i expect:

```
 +---------+----+----+-----+--------+
 | service | ad | op | sub | pushed |
 +---------+----+----+-----+--------+
 |  CHOO   | 96 | x  |  1  |    0   |
 |  CHOO   | 98 | x  |  2  |    0   |
 |  HOORAY | 96 | x  |  1  |    1   |
 |  DANG   | 96 | x  |  2  |    2   |
 +---------+----+----+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to join together your two current subqueries.  I have used a full outer join below, because we want to handle the possibity that a service may appear in only the `subs` or `buff` table, but not both.

```
SELECT t1.service,
       t1.ad,
       t1.op,
       t1.sub,
       COALESCE(t2.pushed, 0) AS pushed
FROM
(
    SELECT service, ad, op, COUNT(*) AS sub
    FROM subs
    WHERE act = 1
    GROUP BY service,ad,op
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT service, COUNT(1) AS pushed
    FROM buff a
    WHERE sub = 'daily'
    GROUP BY service
) t2
    ON t1.service = t2.service
UNION
SELECT t2.service,
       COALESCE(t1.ad, -1),
       COALESCE(t1.op, -1),
       COALESCE(t1.sub, -1),
       t2.pushed
FROM
(
    SELECT service, ad, op, COUNT(*) AS sub
    FROM subs
    WHERE act = 1
    GROUP BY service,ad,op
) t1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT service, COUNT(1) AS pushed
    FROM buff a
    WHERE sub = 'daily'
    GROUP BY service
) t2
    ON t1.service = t2.service
```

Comment: it works. thank you so much for helping. God bless you :)

Comment: @ArifinaIstighfariZahro Aplogies for the really ugly outer join.  If you are certain that one of the two tables is guaranteed to have all services present in the other table, then you can get away with just one half of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

use database name as table name prefix with dot, I don't check the below sentence, it only show the idea:

```
 SELECT service, ad, op, count(1) AS sub FROM core.subs AS t1
 LEFT JOIN push.buff AS t2 ON t1.service=t2.service WHERE t1.act=1
 AND sub = 'daily' GROUP BY t1.service,t1.ad,t1.op
```